# When creating a spatial index, about the 'cells_per_object' setting in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019, spatial-index

When creating a spatial index in SQL Server, if the 'cells_per_object' setting is not specified, is it set to the default value of 16, or does SQL Server adjust it appropriately?

And If it is automatically optimized, can you explain how it operates?
I am using SQL Server 2019. Thank you